I want to build a video calling application using WebRTC. But in my case the video of remote renderer is not coming
I want to build a video calling application using WebRTC. But in my case the video of remote renderer is not coming. I have set up a signalling server using socket.io for exchanging SDP and ICE candidates. Also I have printed the logs of SDP and ICE Candidates. They are also coming. BUt  SDP and ICE Candidates are exchanging successfully through the signalling server. But still the remote video is not coming.
Here print("ICE connection state: $state"); this thing is giving output as

ICE connection state: RTCIceConnectionState.RTCIceConnectionStateFailed

and print("Peer connection state: $state"); this gives output as

Peer connection state: RTCPeerConnectionState.RTCPeerConnectionStateFailed.

I don't know why.
Here is my code:
Please check the code and tell me what is wrong here.
class VideoCallScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final IO.Socket socket;
  final String roomId;
  final bool isCaller;
  final String receiverId;

  VideoCallScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.socket,
    required this.roomId,
    required this.isCaller,
    required this.receiverId,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoCallScreenState createState() => _VideoCallScreenState();
}

class _VideoCallScreenState extends State<VideoCallScreen> {
  final _localRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
  final _remoteRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
  RTCPeerConnection? _peerConnection;
  MediaStream? _localStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeWebRTC();
    _initializeRenderers();
 }

  Future<void> _initializeRenderers() async {
    await _localRenderer.initialize();
    await _remoteRenderer.initialize();
    print("Local and remote renderers initialized");
  }

  Future<void> _initializeWebRTC() async {
    _localStream = await _getUserMedia();
    _localRenderer.srcObject = _localStream;
    print("Local stream initialized with ID: ${_localStream?.id}");

    _peerConnection = await _createPeerConnection();

    _peerConnection!.onIceConnectionState = (RTCIceConnectionState state) {
      print("ICE connection state: $state");
};

_peerConnection!.onConnectionState = (RTCPeerConnectionState state) {
  print("Peer connection state: $state");
};

// Handle ICE candidates
_peerConnection!.onIceCandidate = (RTCIceCandidate candidate) {
  if (candidate != null) {
    print("ICE candidate generated: ${candidate.candidate}");
    widget.socket.emit('ice-candidate', {
      'roomId': widget.roomId,
      'candidate': candidate.toMap(),
      'to': widget.receiverId,
    });
  }
};

// Listen for remote tracks (streams)
_peerConnection!.onTrack = (RTCTrackEvent event) {
  print("Received remote track event");
  if (event.track.kind == 'video') {
    setState(() {
      _remoteRenderer.srcObject = event.streams[0];
      print("Remote stream added: ${event.streams[0].id}");
    });

    // Check video tracks
    event.streams[0].getVideoTracks().forEach((track) {
      print("Remote video track: ${track.id}, Enabled: ${track.enabled}");
    });
  }
};

_setupSignalingListeners();

if (widget.isCaller) {
  widget.socket.on('call-accepted', (_) async {
    print("Call accepted, creating offer");
    RTCSessionDescription offer = await _peerConnection!.createOffer();
    await _peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(offer);

    widget.socket.emit('offer-sdp', {
      'roomId': widget.roomId,
      'sdp': offer.sdp,
      'type': offer.type,
      'to': widget.receiverId,
    });
  });
}
}

 void _setupSignalingListeners() {
   widget.socket.on('offer', (data) async {
   print("Received offer: ${data['sdp']}");
   RTCSessionDescription offer = RTCSessionDescription(data['sdp'], data['type']);
   await _peerConnection!.setRemoteDescription(offer);

  RTCSessionDescription answer = await _peerConnection!.createAnswer();
  await _peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(answer);

  widget.socket.emit('answer-sdp', {
    'roomId': widget.roomId,
    'sdp': answer.sdp,
    'type': answer.type,
    'to': widget.receiverId,
  });
});

widget.socket.on('answer-sdp', (data) async {
  print("Received answer: ${data['sdp']}");
  RTCSessionDescription answer = RTCSessionDescription(data['sdp'], data['type']);
  await _peerConnection!.setRemoteDescription(answer);
});

widget.socket.on('ice-candidate', (data) async {
  print("Received ICE candidate: ${data['candidate']['candidate']}");
  RTCIceCandidate candidate = RTCIceCandidate(
    data['candidate']['candidate'],
    data['candidate']['sdpMid'],
    data['candidate']['sdpMLineIndex'],
  );
  await _peerConnection!.addCandidate(candidate);
  print("Candidate added to peer connection.");
});
}

Future<RTCPeerConnection> _createPeerConnection() async {
Map<String, dynamic> configuration = {
  'iceServers': [
    {'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
  ],
};

RTCPeerConnection pc = await createPeerConnection(configuration);
_localStream!.getTracks().forEach((track) {
  pc.addTrack(track, _localStream!);
});

return pc;
}

Future<MediaStream> _getUserMedia() async {
final Map<String, dynamic> mediaConstraints = {
  'audio': true,
  'video': {
    'mandatory': {
      'minWidth': '320',
      'minHeight': '240',
      'minFrameRate': '10',
    },
    'facingMode': 'user',
  },
};

return await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
}

Future<void> _getWebRTCStats() async {
if (_peerConnection != null) {
  var stats = await _peerConnection!.getStats();
  stats.forEach((report) {
    print('Report: ${report.id}');
    print('Type: ${report.type}');
    print('Timestamp: ${report.timestamp}');
    report.values.forEach((key, value) {
      print('$key: $value');
    });
  });
} else {
  print("Peer connection is not established");
}
}

@override
void dispose() {
_localRenderer.dispose();
_remoteRenderer.dispose();
_localStream?.dispose();
_peerConnection?.dispose();
super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Video Call'),
  ),
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned.fill(
        child: RTCVideoView(_localRenderer),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
          ),
          child: RTCVideoView(_remoteRenderer),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.call_end, color: Colors.red),
              onPressed: () {
                _peerConnection?.close();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.bar_chart, color: Colors.blue),
              onPressed: () {
                _getWebRTCStats();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}

